Git-Credential-Manager on WSL 2.2.2 Fails with XOpenDisplay Failed. Worked fine on WSL 2.1.5.0
I recently upgraded WSL 2.2.2.0 to resolve and issue with the Linux Filesystem Not Showing in Explorer.
Since doing that, I am unable to do a git push or anything requiring authentication to github.
This worked on WSL 2.1.5.0
I can still run XApps (XClock / XTerm) or other XWindow based apps on WSL 2.2.2.0, except the error GitCredentialManager.
I'm using VcXSrv X Server for my XWindows Server.
Normally when executing a code that requires authentication, I would get an authentication window.
However, this is what I get now.
git push
Unhandled exception. System.Exception: XOpenDisplay failed
   at Avalonia.X11.AvaloniaX11Platform.Initialize(X11PlatformOptions options)
   at Avalonia.AvaloniaX11PlatformExtensions.<>c.<UseX11>b__0_0()
   at Avalonia.AppBuilder.SetupUnsafe()
   at Avalonia.AppBuilder.Setup()
   at Avalonia.AppBuilder.SetupWithoutStarting()
   at GitCredentialManager.UI.AvaloniaUi.<>c__DisplayClass8_1.<ShowWindowAsync>b__1(CancellationToken appCancelToken)
   at GitCredentialManager.UI.Dispatcher.DispatcherJob.Execute(CancellationToken ct)
   at GitCredentialManager.UI.Dispatcher.DispatcherJobQueue.Run()
   at GitCredentialManager.UI.Dispatcher.Run()
   at GitCredentialManager.Program.Main(String[] args)


I rolled back by installing WSL 2.1.5.0 and everything is working again. Filed an issue with https://github.com/microsoft/wsl
